# "systemctl daemon-reload" after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 I cannot start chromium or firefox anymore

Tags: upgrade, firefox, snap, chromium, cgroup

I upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04. (I use fluxbox as windowmanager)
I'm aware that firefox is now a snap (like chromium) but now I cannot start firefox nor chromium anymore.
In both cases I get `/system.slice/lightdm.service is not a snap cgroup`

What I tried so far:
I removed both snaps and installed them again but I still get the same error message whenever I try to start them